# How to create regex pattern for Number Patterns like AAAABBB and AAABBCC

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

How to create regex pattern for Number Patterns like AAAABBB and AAABBCC. Number matched in the first group should not be considered in the 2nd and later groups.

```
Here:
A = [0-9] Any number between 0 to 9
B = [0-9] Any number between 0 to 9 excluding A
C = [0-9] Any number between 0 to 9 excluding A and B
```

For example : `5555333`, `7777999`, `2225588`, `1113377` etc. I want to find such numbers from the bigger number range using java regex.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this does what you want.  It captures the desired digit, followed by 0 or more of the same digit, not followed by any previous digit using back references in the negative look ahead assertions.

```
String pat = "(\\d)\\1*(?:(\\d)\\2*(?!\\1)){1,2}";
long[] data = {112233, 123333, 888777555, 999666, 222111222,222222, 111122221, 11223344,44442222,444455522, 522212121};
for (long i : data) {
    String s = Long.toString(i);
    System.out.printf("%12s - %s%n", s, s.matches(pat) ? "Valid" : "Invalid");
}
```

Prints

```
      112233 - Valid
      123333 - Valid
   888777555 - Valid
      999666 - Valid
   222111222 - Invalid
      222222 - Valid
   111122221 - Invalid
    11223344 - Invalid
    44442222 - Valid
   444455522 - Valid
   522212121 - Invalid
```

Comment: Thank you so much WJS. It helped me a lot to form different number patterns. I am new to regex and started learning recently. For AAAAABC I wrote this pattern "(\\d)\\1{4}(?=(\\d)(?!\\1))\\2{0}(?:(\\d)\\3{0}(?!\\1)(?!\\2))" but it is also including AAAAAAB and AAAAAAA. How can I exclude these two matches.

Comment: Try this. `String pat = "(\\d)\\1{4}(\\d)(?!\\1)(\\d)(?!\\2)";`